# specified users are not affected by the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

hello in this command if someone give i specified role to someone, bot takes automatically but only the server owner is not affected by this code i want the people i specify to give. Not just the server owner. also not just one user i want multiple user

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const o = await oldMember.guild
    .fetchAuditLogs({ type: "MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE" })
    .then(audit => audit.entries.first());

  const y = o.executor;
  const ass = o.target;
  const k = oldMember.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === "641032067840344064");
  if (y.bot) return;
  let roller = ['653187994655916032', '629749325802766377'];
  if (newMember.guild.owner.id == y.id) return; // this part i think ^^ 
  if (oldMember.roles.size > newMember.roles.size) return;
    let newRoleName = newMember.roles.array();
    let newRole = newMember.guild.roles.find(r => r.id === roller[0]);


      newMember.guild.members.get(ass.id).removeRoles(roller);
      return k.send(
        `${y} adlı yetkili ${newMember} kişisine rol verdi, Tokuchi tarafından rol geri alındı!`
      );

});
```

Comment: oh why i get - reputation i just asked question :(

Comment: Your question isn't well formulated.  That's likely why you are getting the down votes.  The title needs to ask a question, and you need make sure you clearly describe what your code is doing and what you expect it to be doing.  Read over [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @TokuchiLémperouge it's okay man. I also got downvotes before. Just make sure to clarify your question and explain it clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm turkish person ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to specify who is immune to having their role removed. Currently it's only the guild owner.

Define your own list of user ids and use:

```js
if (<list with user ids>.includes(y.id)) return;
```